# Mixed symmetry of rank $3$ tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, representation-theory

I have rank 3 tensor $T_{ijk}$ with following properties:

$T_{ijk}=T_{jik}$

$T_{ijk}=-T_{kji}$

Is it true that there is the only one tensor of rank 3 with those properties and it is $T_{ijk}=0$.
I'm starting from the following

$T_{ijk}=-T_{kij}=-T_{ikj}=T_{jki}=T_{kji}=-T_{ijk}$

$\Rightarrow 2T_{ijk}=0$

$\Rightarrow T_{ijk}=0$

Where am I making a mistake? Because the result is strange enough. Does this mean that from the point of view of Young diagrams, the hook is not interesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question and accepted answer here miss the main point, which is that for tensors of mixed symmetry, the *indices themselves* do *not* obey that symmetry, which is somewhat counterintuitive. This is explained in the comments by Michael Seifert [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80811).

Tensors of mixed symmetry are generated by applying Young symmetrizers. In your case, you want to generate a tensor with symmetry

<kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd> 
 <kbd>3</kbd>

which means that to an arbitrary tensor $T_{ijk}$, you apply the symmetrizers
$$[e-(13)][e+(12)]T$$
where $e$ is the identity permutation, so that you get the desired tensor
$$T_{ijk}+T_{jik}-T_{kji}-T_{jki}$$
which is non-trivial.

For your method, you correctly arrived at the conclusion that the only tensor with $T_{ijk}=T_{jik}$ and $T_{ijk}=-T_{kji}$ is the zero tensor. It is not the right way to generate tensors of mixed symmetry, for the reasons mentioned at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer makes everything clear in my head

Comment: Maybe I am a little dyslexic and read things backwards, but the Young symmetrizers yielding  the desired tensor are in the opposite order, no? The order you chose in the penultimate equation is that of [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_symmetrizer#Construction), and since the two aggressively do not commute...

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm not too sure what WP is. Anyway I used the convention from Hamermesh's book, where the symmetrizers (rows) are applied before the antisymmetrizers (columns). And the OP wanted to symmetrize 12 and antisymmetrize 13.

Comment: WP = Wikipedia, which I linked: see bottom of their section. I suspect I'm reading your convention backwards.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yeah. The Wikipedia article antisymmetrizes (13) *before* symmetrizing (12). However I used the opposite convention where I symmetrized (12) first. That's why the last term differs. For me it's 231 but for Wikipedia, it's 312. Basically the permutation group is non-abelian.

Answer (score 0):

Your work seems fine. This little fact is sometimes known as the $S_3$-lemma, and it can be stated in a very general way: if $S$ is a non-empty set, $G$ is a (say, abelian) group without elements or order $2$, and $T: S\times S \times S \to G$ is symmetric in the first pair, and skew-symmetric on the second pair, then $T =0$.

$$T(x,y,z) = T(y,x,z)=-T(y,z,x)=-T(z,y,x) = T(z,x,y) = T(x,z,y) = -T(x,y,z).$$

The fact that tensors represent multilinear maps is irrelevant here. If $G$ is non-abelian, same proof works replacing minus signs with inverses (this is what would be understood as skew-symmetry).

Comment: Thanks! But my question arises - what does this mean at the level of the Young diagram for such a tensor? Indeed, such a diagram describes a trivial tensor?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Young diagrams, it's just an elementary algebra fact. You use this to show other things. For example, if $(M,g)$ is an even-dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifold and $N$ is a null mid-dimensional submanifold, then $N$ is totally geodesic by the $S_3$-lemma applied to the map $(X,Y,Z) \mapsto g(\nabla_XY,Z)$ defined on triples of vector fields on $N$.

Comment: I mean that a tensor of this type can be described in the language of a Young diagram - a hook. And the interpretation of such a diagram is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with Young diagrams, but the fact remains that a tensor with those two symmetries is the zero tensor. So whatever diagram corresponds to those symmetries should be non-interesting.